# How to Sync Progressbar with ListBox Items Removal c#

Tags: c#

I've a project in which i got a listBox1 a timer1 a button1 and a progressBar1.

When i click button1 the timer1 starts.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Interval = 500;
        progressBar1.Maximum = listBox1.Items.Count;
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
    }
```

When timer1 ticks it removes one item from listBox1 and progressBar1 must show the progress of Removal.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        {

            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
            progressBar1.Increment(1);
            groupBox1.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
        }
        if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            progressBar1.Maximum = listBox1.Items.Count;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
    }
```

But i think the above code got some bug with progressBar1 as it dont show progress while removal of items and it is full when the listBox1 items = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way than this, So set the step property like this in click event :

```
       this.progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        this.progressBar1.Value = 0;
        this.progressBar1.Maximum = this.listBox1.Items.Count;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;
```

Now you can do the following:

```
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        {

            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            groupBox1.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            this.timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Complete Code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PopulateList();
    }

    private void PopulateList()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(i);
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            groupBox1.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Interval = 500;
        progressBar1.Enabled = true;
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = listBox1.Items.Count;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the timer in button click? Also is the list box items there before we are setting the max value on progress bar?

Comment: yes i have enabled timer and set interval at click.yes the listbox items are generated before click event.

Comment: I have put the complete code I tried with the answer above and it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

You are setting progressbar value to 0 after incrementing it...

Try this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
        groupBox1.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will throw an exception when there will be 0 items in listBox1.

Comment: Why would it? We are only removing items when: if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)

Comment: Thanks@jmelhus I Got it//

Comment: I did the same thing jmelhus did, I was just too slow (: and it does not throw an exception. Already tried it out

Comment: @Dr.zeus I'm glad I was able to help :) Please mark the answer as accepted if this was your solution :)